# Obtain full v2 REST url?

Tags: theme-development, rest-api

In my themes `functions.php` I call `get_rest_url()` and I get the url `http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/`. But thats not the full url. I need something like `http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/`

Is there a WordPress function that will give me this url?

Answer (score 4):

You could add the path argument to the `get_rest_url()` function as per the WordPress Developer docs - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_rest_url/ - in order to get the path you need:

`get_rest_url( null, 'wp/v2/' );`

This would produce: http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/

Comment: thanks, will all versions of WordPress have/handle `wp/v2`? I don't want to hardcode this. This is why I am using `get_rest_url()` otherwise I would just hard code `/wp-json/wp/v2` and not use the function at all.

Comment: As far as I know this is the only way to get that path, as per the Codex - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_rest_url/ - I would imagine that if there's ever a v3 then the v2 would remain in place.

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: @JakeM, I don't know about the `wp` part, but as the name implies it is very possible that there will be a `v3` and you will have to hardcode as different versions will have different format of inputs and outputs

Comment: Could you please accept my answer if it helped?